# Paypal Standard - is it possible to keep user on site

Tags: paypal

Just as the question title explains - when using paypal standard, is it possible to keep the user on site instead of directing them to paypal to log in and authorise the payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Website Payments Standard (the regular HTML-based 'Buy now' / 'Add to cart' buttons): no. This is not possible.
You'll need to integrate with an API-based solution such as Adaptive Embedded Payments or Express Checkout for Digital Goods if you want the buyer to remain on your site and still pay with PayPal.

Comment: thanks, its just so confusing with all the different types of 'flows'.  Im a bit lost to be honest.  I looking to build an adaptive api integration and am having trouble deciding what the flow should be here.  I though maybe we could keep customer on site but also couldnt decide between express and standard type flows

Answer (score 0):

It may provide a better purchase flow if PayPal could be integrated into your website, but would users know they're actually logging into PayPal and that their user id/passwords are not being compromised?